# Create radioList in Yii2 using active records

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

```
$list = [];
foreach($choices as $choice)
{
    ArrayHelper::map($list, $choice->id, $choice->choice_text);            
}
echo $form->field($model, 'choice_text')->radioList($list)->label(false);
```

`$choices` is passed from a view which contains all objects of model choice. I need to create an array which maps `$choice->id` to `$choice->choice_text`. How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$list = ArrayHelper::map($choices, 'id', 'choice_text');
$form->field($model, 'id')->radioList($list)->label(false);
```

See https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/helper-array#building-maps for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
$list = [];
foreach($choices as $choice)
{
    $list = $list + [$choice->id=>$choice->choice_text];            
}
echo $form->field($model, 'choice_text')->radioList($list)->label(false);
```